# How to prove $a^TX^{T}(XX^T)^{-2}Xa$ is increasing when the dimension of $X$ and $a$ increases?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X_1\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with $n\geq m$ and $rank(X_1)=m$, $a_1\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $z\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $w\in\mathbb{R}$. Define
$$
\begin{aligned}
&X_2=(X_1,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times (n+1)}\
&a_2=(a_1^T,w)^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}
\end{aligned}
Assume $X_2$ has full row rank. Now I want to show that

$$
a_2^TX_2^T(X_2X_2^T)^{-2}X_2a_2\geq a_1^TX_1^T(X_1X_1^T)^{-2}X_1a_1
$$

I know that, by Sherman–Morrison formula,
$$
(X_2X_2^T)^{-1}=(X_1X_1^T+zz^T)^{-1}=(X_1X_1^T)^{-1}-\frac{1}{g}(X_1X_1^T)^{-1}zz^T(X_1X_1^T)^{-1},
$$
where $g=1+z^T(X_1X_1^T)^{-1}z$. Then we can write $a_2X_2^T(X_2X_2^T)^{-2}X_2a_2$ in terms of $X_1$ and $a_1$. But then I got stuck. Is there any convenient way to proof it?

Comment: @user1551 Sorry, it's my typo. I should say $rank(X)=m$, so $XX^T$ is invertible. Then how to further prove the statement?

Comment: @user1551 Sorry for my careless editing. What I want to say is that $X_2$ still has full row rank so $X_2X_2^T$ is invertible. I think now the question should make more sense to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Counterexample:
$$
X_1=I_2,\ a_1=\pmatrix{1\\ 0},\ X_2=\pmatrix{1&0&1\\ 0&1&1},\ a_2=\pmatrix{1\\ 0\\ -1}.
$$
$$
a_2^TX_2^T(X_2X_2^T)^{-2}X_2a_2 = \frac{5}{9}
< 1 = a_1^TX_1^T(X_1X_1^T)^{-2}X_1a_1.
$$